# Stacking nested Divs like accordion (without plugin) for dynamic content and varying nested structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

update: made more progress to show all child elements- https://jsfiddle.net/zigzag/jstuq9ok/11/ Now just need to address this for subsecond area to display also. If you now click on Lily, shen and another shen show up but if you now click on shen to drill down, it just hides it. thoughts?

I want to be clear that in this case data is coming from a source system, so we won't want/like to hard code things. That said, here is the structure we want...

1. Adam
2. Lily

2.1 Sen

2.1.1 Tank

2.2 Another Sen

3. Justin

Thanks to online contributing community, I got that far . progress: https://jsfiddle.net/zigzag/jstuq9ok/10/

You will notice that when you click on Lily, you will only see Sen and not the Another Sen. I tried placing markup with 2.2 ahead of 2.1.1 and vice versa but neither worked. I'm sure i'm missing something in jQuery DOM traversal.

```js
  $('.menu-toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent <a> to redirect to the top of the page
    $('.row:not(.sub):not(.subsecond)').not($('.sub').prev('.row')).not($('.subsecond').prev('.row')).not($(this).closest('.row')).find('span.glyphicon-menu-up').toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-down glyphicon-menu-up');
    $(this).find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-down glyphicon-menu-up');
    var Nextrow = $(this).closest('.row').next('.row'); // get the next row
    if (Nextrow.hasClass('sub')) { // if next row has class sub
      $('.sub').not(Nextrow).hide(); // hide all sub but not this one
      Nextrow.slideToggle(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':hidden')) {
          $('.subsecond').hide();
          $('span.glyphicon-menu-up').toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-down glyphicon-menu-up');
        }
      }); // toggle this sub row
      return false;
    }
    if (Nextrow.hasClass('subsecond')) { // if next row has class subsecond
      $('.subsecond').not(Nextrow).hide(); // hide all subsecond but not this one
      Nextrow.slideToggle(); // toggle this subsecond row
      return false;
    }
  });
```

```css
.pageArea {
  background-color: black;
}

.orgChart {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: gray;
  font-family: segoe UI;
  color: white;
}

.img_title {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.empDetails {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
}

a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
  color: white;
}

.toggle_class {
  text-align: right;
}

.sub {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.subsecond {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container pageArea">
  <div class="row orgChart">
    <div class="col-sm-2 img_tile">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 empDetails">
      <h4>
        Adam
      </h4>
      <p>
        Director
      </p>
      <p>
        Ensure quality and timely delivery through resource and time management.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row orgChart">
    <div class="col-sm-2 img_tile">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 empDetails">
      <h4>
        Lily
      </h4>
      <p>
        Project Manager
      </p>
      <p>
        Ensure quality and timely delivery through resource and time management.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 toggle_button">
      <a class="menu-toggle" href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row orgChart sub">
    <div class="col-sm-2 img_tile">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 empDetails">
      <h4>
        Sen
      </h4>
      <p>
        Team Lead
      </p>
      <p>
        Ensure quality and timely delivery through resource and time management.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 toggle_button">
      <a class="menu-toggle" href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row orgChart sub">
    <div class="col-sm-2 img_tile">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 empDetails">
      <h4>
        Other Sen
      </h4>
      <p>
        Team Lead
      </p>
      <p>
        Ensure quality and timely delivery through resource and time management.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row orgChart subsecond">
    <div class="col-sm-2 img_tile">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 empDetails">
      <h4>
        Tank
      </h4>
      <p>
        Designer
      </p>
      <p>
        Ensure quality and timely delivery through resource and time management.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 toggle_button">
      <a class="menu-toggle" href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row orgChart">
    <div class="col-sm-2 img_tile">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 empDetails">
      <h4>
        Justin
      </h4>
      <p>
        Director
      </p>
      <p>
        Ensure quality and timely delivery through resource and time management.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 toggle_button">
      <a class="menu-toggle" href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not wrapping all `sub` in the same DIV, it will be easy to handle instead of having many sub

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to [THIS](https://jsfiddle.net/as2xd62k/12/)

Comment: similar. in my case it will be nested. my jsfiddle best displays the layout of tile like display.

Comment: Nvm, for anyone looking for answer. this is fixed here: https://jsfiddle.net/zigzag/nmdcef7L/

Answer (score 0):

Your are changing only "next" row. ( $(this).closest('.row').next('.row'); ) I guess you wan`t to target next AND all the siblings rows.

As Temani pointet in his comment would be easier if you make nested divs grouping the rows that should open together.

```js
$('span').click(function(){
  $('.sublevel').addClass('toClose');/*close all*/
  $(this).next('.sublevel').removeClass('toClose');/*but not the one after this toggler*/
  $(this).next('.sublevel').parents('.sublevel').removeClass('toClose');/*and also keep open it's ancestors*/
  $('.sublevel.toClose').hide();/*hide ones to close*/
  $('.sublevel:not(.toClose)').show();/*show the others*/
  $('.sublevel.toClose').removeClass('toClose');/*tidy up*/
  }
);
```

```css
div{padding-left:2rem;}
.sublevel{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
1 Adam
</div>

<div>
2 Lily<span>[toggler]</span>
  <div class="sublevel">
    <div>
      2.1 Sen<span>[toggler]</span>
      <div class="sublevel">
        2.1.1 Tank
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      2.2 Another Sen
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
3 Justin<span>[toggler]</span>
  <div class="sublevel">
    <div>
      3.1 someone
    </div>
    <div>
      3.2 someother<span>[toggler]</span>
      <div class="sublevel">
        3.1.1 this one
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      3.3 someother 2
    </div>
    <div>
      3.4 someother 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess I can try this. one issue I had - after everything is expanded, when I click on Lily, it doesn't collapse the child under Lily (2).

Comment: If you want to close all the sublevels under the closing ones you coud do $('.sublevel.toClose').find('.sublevel').hide(); before $('.sublevel.toClose').hide();